# Parse time error Fatal error: Uncaught DateMalformedStringException:

Tags: php, datetime

I'm studying the date function in PHP and ran into the same problem. An error occurs in my code that works with a large date. Help me understand what the problem is with this code.

```
   $start = new DateTime('02.12.20239');
   var_dump($start);
```

This code throws an error:
Fatal error: Uncaught DateMalformedStringException: Failed to parse time string (02.12.20239) at position 10 (9): Unexpected character in C:\Projects\Php\test1\test1.php:2
How to work with large dates in php?

Comment: Did you mean 2023 instead of 20239?

$start = new DateTime('02.12.2023');
var_dump($start );

Answer (score 1):

The default date formats are limited to 4-digit years. If you want to create a date with a larger year, you need to use a custom
format based on `X` (as mentioned [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php)):

> X and x: A full numeric representation of a year, up to 19 digits, optionally prefixed by + or -

Example:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.X', '02.12.20239');
echo $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

Output:

```
02.12.20239
```